# Using AWK to convert a text file to csv

Tags: csv, awk

I have a very large text file that contains a line that begins with a specifically formatted and predictable "code" followed by one or more lines of text and then another code line followed by one or more lines of text. My goal is to create from this mess a `csv` file that contains the code line as the first field and then a second field that contains all lines following the code until the next code line is encountered. If I could also include the code line in the second field, that would really help. But if not possible....

So my text file resembles:

```
54-332
line of text 1
line of text 2
line of text 3
54-334
line of text 1
line of text 2
line of text 3
line of text 4
```

and I am looking to get a `CSV` file, importable into `Excel` or `MySQL` that should look something like:

```
"54-332","line of text 1 line of text 2 line of text3"
"54-334","line of text 1 line of text 2 line of text3 line of text4"
```

I've been able to write the part that identifies the code but am stumped on how to do the rest. The text has no reliable field separator, just the record separator (the code).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cryptic but does the job:

```
$ awk '{$1=q s q","q $1;$0=$0q;s=RT}NR>1' RS="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" q='"' file
"54-332","line of text 1 line of text 2 line of text 3"
"54-334","line of text 1 line of text 2 line of text 3 line of text 4"
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks very very much. My code field is always of the form of 3-333.33 where the 3s can be any integer. Also, the code is always the first field on the line. I made a file of the data that I used in my question and ran your routine against it but as no results came I assume that I am running it incorrectly. What I did was paste your code on the command line and substituted the file that I created for file. I was expecting the results to come to the screen. What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I am just beginning to learn AWK and SED.

Comment: With your example file using `xx-xxx` as the distinguishing separator and `GNU awk` this will work. What system are you on and what version of awk do you have? For your actual file taking `x-xxx.xx` as the separator you would do change `RS` to `RS="[0-9]-[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{2}"`

Comment: Centos 6.3 GNU Awk 3.1.7
I made the change to the RS but still I have no output. Assuming my data file is named test.dat would I execute this by:

Comment: Continuing-- Would I execute by: awk '{$1=q s q","q $1;$0=$0q;s=RT}NR>1' RS="[0-9]-[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{2}" q='"' test.dat    Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This is problem when your question does represent your real problem.

Comment: Sorry, had to connect to work remotely to get the actual code. Still, I do not receive any results when I run the AWK command against a file containing the data I used in my question. Also, sudo_O, thanks again for the idea. I'm not clear on the q='"' at the end. Could you explain what this is-- would appreciate very much.

Comment: It just set a variable `q` to a double quote character, saves nasty quoting headaches.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I am running your script against a file containing the data I used in my question and it doesn't produce any results. Any ideas of why this would be the case? Rough being a noob.

Comment: Try `awk '{$1=q s q","q $1;$0=$0q;s=RT}NR>1' RS="[0-9]+-[0-9]+" q='"' file`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks very much. I wish I had even a small portion of your intelligence. Hard to believe this could be done with a one-line piece of code. Again, my thanks to you.

Comment: Don't believe this is a reflection on my intelligence, it is simple a reflection on the power of `awk`. If your problem is now solved please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to.

Comment: Sorry -- one more problem. I'm having a problem converting to the 3-333.33 code. The period seems to be giving me some sort of a problem. I can use [0-9]+-[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+.   and this works but when I add in the additional +[0-9]+[0-9] it selects the entire file.

Comment: For `x-xxx.xx` the expression would be `[0-9]-[0-9]+[.][0-9]+`.

Comment: That works. I think that if I had an anchor ^ character at the beginning this would work perfectly. I can't seem to get the syntax correct to indicate that the code that I want to use is in the first field.

Comment: More specifically, I see now that the code definition must include the information that it is the first 8 (3-333.33) characters in the line. The reason is that in the remaining lines other codes are referred to  that are also processed as matches. Sorry to have overlooked that but I did. I have since read that anchors should not or cannot be included in RS syntax. I'm beginning to think I might have a lot of cut and paste in my future. This is an 800 page document not of my design. Any other thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a blank line at the top of the file and use `\n[0-9]-[0-9]+[.][0-9]+` to account for the newline add `sub("\n","",RT);` before `s=RT`.

Comment: Totally worked. Thanks so much. Just for interest, is there a way to make the entire code line (there is some text with a period at the end) that makes up the remaining code line.. but is there a way to include this remaining information in the field so that it is contained with the first field of the CSV?

Comment: Great, Don't forget to accept this answer.. I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: The line that contains the code (3-333.33) in my raw text file also contains some additional text. This text string ends with a period. I just wondered that if there is a way that this additional text could be included in the first field of the CSV that currently contains just the code (3-333.33). Sorry for the garbled explanation previously.

Comment: Yes just extend RS to match it, something like `\n[0-9]-[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[^.]+[.]`.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. Really appreciate your help and patience. Let me know if in return for your help I could buy you dinner and several refreshing beverages via PayPal or something. This is going to make a huge difference as I have many such text conversions on the horizon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This Ruby script could also help. It's safe for converting input to CSV format including those with double quotes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

a = []
r = Regexp.new(/^[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+$/)
o = { :force_quotes => true }

File.open(ARGV.shift).each_line do |l|
  l.chomp!
  if r =~ l && !a.empty?
    t = [a.shift]
    t << a.join(' ') unless a.empty?
    puts t.to_csv(o)
    a.clear
  end
  a << l
end

if !a.empty?
  t = [a.shift]
  t << a.join(' ') unless a.empty?
  puts t.to_csv(o)
end
```

You can change the regular expression if necessary. To run the script, do:

```
ruby script.rb file > output.csv
```

This script on the other hand would make sure that there are always two columns:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

r = Regexp.new(/^[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+$/)
o = { :force_quotes => true }

a = []
b = []

File.open(ARGV.shift).each_line do |l|
  l.chomp!
  if r =~ l
    puts [a.shift, b.join(' ')].to_csv(o) unless (a.empty? && b.empty?)
    a = [l]
    b.clear
  else
    b << l
  end
end

puts [a.shift, b.join(' ')].to_csv(o) unless (a.empty? && b.empty?)
```